# Equivalent of Swift Dotted Loop and Map in Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have this code in swift

```
animation.keyTimes = (0...count).map { 
    NSNumber(value: CFTimeInterval($0) / CFTimeInterval(count)) 
}
```

I want to convert it into objective C. I am not sure how to use triple dot operator in objective C along with the map.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html):

> The closed range operator (*a...b*) defines a range that runs from a to b, and **includes the values a and b**. The value of a must not be greater than b.

So, i believe this should work fine:

```
NSMutableArray *result = [NSMutableArray array];

for (NSInteger i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
    [result addObject: [NSNumber numberWithInteger:i]];
}

animation.keyTimes = result
```

Comment: Thank you. I got the idea from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This dot notation and mapping doesn't exist as first class citizens in Objective-C.

You could try `Ranges` (`NSMakeRange(0, count);`) and then enumerate the range.

Or you can write your own map function on a range or an array and use that.

Answer (score 1):

> `...` operator and `.map` method are available in swift only. So you can do it in objective-c like given below.

```
NSMutableArray *keyTimes = [NSMutableArray array];

for(int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
 [keyTimes addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger: CFTimeInterval(i)/CFTimeInterval(count)];
}

animation.keyTimes = keyTimes
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct equivalent for the *closed range operator* and `map` in Objective-C.

An *analogous translation* is `NSRange`, `NSIndexSet` and `enumerateIndexes...`

```
NSInteger startIndex = 0;
NSInteger count = 100;
NSIndexSet *indexSet = [NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndexesInRange: NSMakeRange(startIndex, count + 1)];

__block NSMutableArray<NSNumber *> * keyTimes = [NSMutableArray array];
[indexSet enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL * _Nonnull stop) {
    [keyTimes addObject: [NSNumber numberWithDouble: (double)idx / (double)count]];
}];
NSLog(@"%@", keyTimes);
```